# access json nested array from factory angular

Tags: json, angularjs

in my angular app I use a factory which get json data and pass it to a controller. it is working for me if I use simple json array but fails in a nested array
in case of a simple json file I have this structure

```
[
          {
            "name": "bond_1",
            "profession": "Programmer",
            "hometown": "St Louis, MO"
          },
          {
            "name": "bond_2",
            "profession": "Salesman",
            "hometown": "Denver, CO"
          },
          {
            "name": "bond_3",
            "profession": "CEO",
            "hometown": "San Francisco, CA"
          }
]
```

my factory is this

```
.factory('Topology', function ($http){
 var data = [];
 return{
    get: function(){
        if (data.length == 0){
           $http.get("data.json") 
           .success(function (response){
               for(var i=0, ii=response.length; i<ii; i++){
                   data.push(response [i]);
               }
           });
        }
        return data;
    },
  }
});
```

and my controller is this

```
var installerControllers =angular.module('installerControllers', []);
installerControllers.controller('stageThreeCtrl', function ($scope,   Topology) {
       $scope.bonds=Topology.get();
})
```

now it all working fine and I can view the data when I doing ng-repeat on it from the view

but i need instead of the simple json structure use a nested array which looks like this

```
{
"bonds":[
        {
        "name": "Alex",
        "profession": "Programmer",
        "hometown": "St Louis, MO"
      },
      {
        "name": "David",
        "profession": "Salesman",
        "hometown": "Denver, CO"
      },
      {
        "name": "Laura",
        "profession": "CEO",
        "hometown": "San Francisco, CA"
      }
],
"networks":[
      {
      "name": "test",
      "all_hosts": "false",
      "IP_Version": "IPV4",
      "IP address": "10.10.10.10",
      "IPV net mask": "255.255.255.0",
      "Interface": "bond 0",
      "VLAN TAG": "4001",
      "Description": "some custom description"
    }
  ]
}
```

now I am trying  to call for one of the objects from the controller in this way

```
var installerControllers =angular.module('installerControllers', []);
installerControllers.controller('stageThreeCtrl', function ($scope, Topology) {
   var data=Topology.get();
   $scope.bonds=data.bonds;  
})
```

but it is not working and I got in the console.log an empty array

your help will be very appreciated

Comment: it looks like an async issue, by the time your $scope.bonds = data.bonds gets executed, the get() has not been resolved, hence the empty array.

Comment: try to put a small delay between var data = Topology.get(); and the assignment   $scope.bonds = data.bonds;  in order to prove if it's an async issue

Comment: how can i add this delay?

Comment: As Jax says, there is an async issue, what you need to do is include `$q` into that factory and use that to project out the data.

Comment: hi I will appreciate if you can show me an example to using the $q as just starting to learn Angular I don't know how to implement it

Comment: This doesn't look like an async issue to me, in angular, thanks to the digest cycle. When the $http request completes, the digest cycle will start which will update the view with the new values in the array that was returned. The console.log being empty is of course an async issue, but the view should still update when the request is complete. i suspect an issue in the view.

Comment: Note, with your new data format, `var data = [];` should be `var data = {};`, and you shouldn't use `.push`, instead use assignment `data[key] = response[key]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is NOT an asynchronous problem, you simply aren't referencing your new data format properly. I've substituted the `$http` call with a `$timeout` since I don't have a server to test against that returns your data. Since your data format has changed, you need to change the way you're referencing it in the factory, controller, and view.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []).factory('Topology', function ($timeout){
  var data = {}; // no longer an array
  
  return{
    get: function(){
        if (!data.bonds){
           $timeout(function () {
               data.bonds = [{name: 'Hello World!'}]; // this would be response.bonds
               data.networks = [{name: 'Hello World!'}]; // this would be response.networks   
           }, 2000);
        }
        return data;
    },
  }
}).controller('stageThreeCtrl', function ($scope, Topology) {
   var data=Topology.get();
   $scope.data = data; // renamed to data
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <p>wait 2 seconds...</p>
  <ul ng-controller="stageThreeCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="bond in data.bonds">{{bond.name}}</li> <!-- using data.bonds -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

---

A better alternative would be to do some minor restructuring to instead take advantage of the promise returned from `$http`.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []).factory('Topology', function ($http){
  var promise;

  return{
    get: function(){
        if (!promise){
          promise = $http.get("data.json");
        }
        return promise;
    },
  }
}).controller('stageThreeCtrl', function ($scope, Topology) {
   Topology.get().then(function (response) {
     $scope.bonds = response.data.bonds;
   });
});
// your original view should now work
```

Comment: This is a better answer. I'm not sure why everyone is using `$q` when `$http` itself returns a promise.

Comment: This is also correct. There is no problem in add $q also. I thought if he need any modification in response he has to use my answer. There is no reason to give me a down vote.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't worked i keep getting empty view
in the html I tried bond in bonds and bond in response.bonds but it is still not working here a link to my page https://preview.c9.io/pnina_lorman/services/angular-seed/app/index.html?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io

Comment: here is also an example that  i did in plnker with your code http://plnkr.co/edit/kF3KpxKix3Vl5pb3hyBa?p=preview

Comment: Here it is working: http://plnkr.co/edit/py5OTeruEw2rkYkKzl8O?p=preview we were using `response` improperly (and the plunkr wasn't including script.js in the html)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   angular.module('app', []).factory('Topology', function ($http,$q){
 return{
    get: function(){
        var d = $q.defer();
           $http.get("data.json") 
           .success(function (response){ 
             console.log(response)
               d.resolve(response);
           });
        return d.promise; 
    },
  }
}).controller('stageThreeCtrl', function ($scope, Topology) {
  Topology.get().then(function (response) {

    $scope.bonds = response.bonds;  
  });
});
```

Comment: the response you geting is a json. So why every one push ing data

Comment: I tried it but it is not working for me please see a plnkr with the implementation http://plnkr.co/edit/6eQSDXqYfwpliBi6Wo9F?p=preview

Comment: can you pls acept the answer

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
Topology.get().then(function (data) {
    $scope.bonds=data.bonds;
});
```

As pointed out in the comments, I didn't notice that the get function wasn't returning a promise.

To return a promise, the $http API is based on the deferred/promise APIs exposed by the $q service, so just use the code below in the get function with the factory (service).

```
return $http.get('data.json');
```

Comment: that won't work because you are not returning a promise from the get function

Comment: hi i tried it but i am getting the error TypeError: Topology.get(...).then is not a function